# switch 12V with 12V ACC (car)

Tags: switches, automotive

I'm currently trying to design a circuit for my car which will switch itself OFF or ON depending on +12V signal from ACC(accessory) cable.

Car is providing me a +12V battery power, +12V accessory power and ground,
i would like to make a circuit which detects +12V on ACC and then uses +12V from battery power.

Obvious solution is to use relay switch, but I'm curious are there any other options how it can be done ?

I'd be grateful for example circuits :)

Comment: Why? Only difference between Accessory and Battery is that Accessory is switched on by the key... essentially a manual relay.

Comment: @Passerby: On quite some systems accessory is regulated to 12V while battery is 12.xV or 13.xV when the motor is running. Additionally this regulation current limits accessory to a few amps max.

Comment: because on this particular acc cable only 100-200mA load is allowed/suggested by manufacturer - and my device will draw ~500mA-1A

Comment: That would be important in the question.  And @plasma I have yet to see a car where that is the situation.

Comment: @Passerby: Try any of those that me and my family had in the last 10 years

Comment: And what about the cigarette lighter receptacle?

Comment: @Passerby: 2009 vw touran

Comment: PlasmaHH and Passerby - I would suspect that cars with regulated 12v acc sockets are ones with "smart" alternators either fitted or likely to be present in the range, which can vary in voltage very widely, from 18V+ to not charging at all. I would imagine most in-car devices are designed to cope with "classic" 13.8 - 14.4v charging but sustained 18v might tip many over the edge into fault state, or "halt-and-catch-fire" for the less well engineered ones. Oh and NoderBlade - use a relay, keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here are options:

1. Transistor with a heatsink if need be
2. Infrared LED along with phototransistor with heatsink if need be

I would only suggest you use these options if you have the components laying around, otherwise you would just be reinventing the wheel as a solid state relay(SSR) is typically made out of one of the options above.

Comment: doesn't a mechanical relay switch also use power constantly because of electromagnet is working constantly ? (in case of monostable switch - because that's the only one I'm interested in)

Comment: @NoderBlade Good point, I'm curious which one uses less energy.

Comment: I found this one - it looks promising i think http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/130e/0900766b8130e53e.pdf

Comment: @NoderBlade That does seem nice. Only 300mW of power for the input, which at 12V input is 25mA.

Comment: Mechanical relays use power while the coil is energised (activated) but not very much, and your car generates a LOT of electricity (typically 50-100 Amps @12v) when running so ~100mA to keep a relay on is a flea fart in a hurricane.